# laravel validation output in ::back controller

Tags: validation, error-handling, laravel

Let me tell you my situation. I have made a simple library/module which I can popupulate in my controller. This way I can use one view file and have different results just by changing some of the $form fields(like text inputs, selects, etc). The example is below:

```
$form = new FormHelper('Webshop bewerken','shop/update',$errors);
$form->addHiddenInput('id',$id);
$form->addTextInput('name','Naam',$item->name);
$form->addTextInput('export','Uitvoer',$item->output_location);
$form->addTextInput('method','Methode',$item->method);
$form->addSidebar();
$form->generateForm();
//show the page
$this->layout->content = View::make('item')->with('form',$form);
```

The problem exist not within the form. This works fine until i need to validate. However the $errors is undefined so i cannot render the errors.

I have noticed that this variable is only available in the view and not in the controller.

This is fine if you have just a few blade.php files but not in my case(many many screens with generic information).

How can I access the $errors variable (output from the laravel validator) in a controller and not view?

Below is a validator code example i use:

```
//run the validator
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
} else {
//do something else(not relevant)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you may use:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

$errors = $validator->errors();
```

This will give you the same errors that you get in the view. To access a particular error you may use:

```
$error = $validator->errors('someFormFieldName')->first();
```